# Why does java.util.Stream's AbstractTask use LEAF_TARGET = ForkJoinPool.getCommonPoolParallelism() << 2?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, forkjoinpool

The idea for setting this Leaf Target is so that there are 4 leaves for every thread; thus if a thread finishes early, it will have plentiful opportunities to work-steal.

But getCommonPoolParallelism() no longer returns #cores.. it instead returns #cores - 1. So why is this the current LEAF_TARGET?

Comment: Does it matter? The comment says "... currently to approximately four tasks per processor". It's probably just a leftover.

Comment: I'd like to think that the JDK developers chose 4 tasks/processor based on benchmarks or real-world experience. And the getCommonPoolParallelism() change would affect results, and be a bug. I'm pretty surprised the LEAF_TARGET is so low to begin with. More leaves = more work stealing opportunity, and since parallel streams should be only be used on large datasets, |data| / ((#core - 1) * 4) size chunks seems big. But like you say, maybe it doesn't matter in the end.